# Globally define non translatable items when using Multilingual app toolkit

Tags: c#, .net, localization, multilingual

When using the Multilingual app toolkit I have a main .resx file which automatically populates all .xlf files of the translations.

In the translation editor there is the possibility to define an item as *non translatable*. So far as I have tried this can be done only on a specific translation because saved in the .xlf file. To make an item non translatable I have to edit all language files in sequence.

Is there a way to do this globally? In my opinion this would make more sense, non translatable items are the same for all languages...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a mechanism in MAT to do this. It would be a good feature to request. If a string shouldn't be translated, then consider whether it can simply be a literal rather than a string resource.

MAT does support adding comments to resources to communicate information to localizers. That info can include things like "Do not translate". Translators may be familiar with the convention of using "{Locked}" in a comment to indicate that a resource should not be localized. This is a convention used in many Microsoft internal localization tools.

It's a good idea to comment resources with information about the context where the string is used, define special terminology, and such. If the string is a format string, you can explain what each of the insertions is (part of speech is important).